# chance public image value in a script from another script in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a radar in my game. By default a image is set shown here (MakeRadarObject) [image].

I'm trying to access and change the image from another script (ScanRadar.cs) so that when the tab matches and I press a button the image shown on the radar will change but I'm having difficulty implementing it and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Here's my scanRadar Script

```
public class RadarScan : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject Enemy;
    Image RadarImageToChange;

    void Start()
    {
        Enemy = GameObject.Find("Enemy");
    }

    public void ChangeImage(Image UpdateImage)
    {
        if (Enemy.tag == "Enemy")
        {
        RadarImageToChange = Enemy.GetComponent<MakeRadarObject>().image;
            UpdateImage = RadarImageToChange;
        }

    }
}
```

Here's my MakeRadObject Script

```
 public Image image;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Radar.RegisterRadarObject(this.gameObject, image);
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    Radar.RemoveRadarObject(this.gameObject); 
}


}
```

Here's my radar Script

```
public class RadarObject
{
public Image icon { get; set; }
public GameObject owner { get; set; }
}

public class Radar : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform playerPos; //position of player
float mapScale = 0.1f; //scale radar size

public static List<RadarObject> radObjects = new List<RadarObject>();

//Registers Object to the radar
public static void RegisterRadarObject(GameObject o, Image i)
{
    Image image = Instantiate(i);
    radObjects.Add(new RadarObject() { owner = o, icon = image }); //adds to List
}

//It loops through the list looking for the owner existing in the list, when it finds the owner is detroys the icon
public static void RemoveRadarObject(GameObject o)
{
    //New list for destroyed objects
    List<RadarObject> newList = new List<RadarObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < radObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        if (radObjects[i].owner == o)
        {
            Destroy(radObjects[i].icon);
            continue;
        }
         else
            newList.Add(radObjects[i]);
        }
    radObjects.RemoveRange(0, radObjects.Count);
    radObjects.AddRange(newList);
}


void DrawRadarDots()
{
    //loops through the list and for each Object it gets the owners transform position and determins the difference between it's
    //position and the players position, does calculations on the angle and distance and position on a circle using polar equations.
    foreach (RadarObject ro in radObjects)
    {
        Vector3 radarPos = (ro.owner.transform.position - playerPos.position);
        float distToObject = Vector3.Distance(playerPos.position, ro.owner.transform.position) * mapScale;
        float deltay = Mathf.Atan2(radarPos.x, radarPos.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 270 - playerPos.eulerAngles.y;
        radarPos.x = distToObject * Mathf.Cos(deltay * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * -1;
        radarPos.z = distToObject * Mathf.Sin(deltay * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

        //grabs icon of players objects and make it a child of panel and set it's postion based on radarPos.x and radarPos.z
        ro.icon.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
        ro.icon.transform.position = new Vector3(radarPos.x, radarPos.z, 0) + this.transform.position;
    }
}

    //Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        DrawRadarDots();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the-same question few days ago? With all the answers you received, and the comments I made, which part of finding the GameObject the script is attached to, getting the script instance with `GetComponent` and then accessing/modifying the target variable is hard?

Comment: Yeah your right  but I'm desperate at this point been reading all over the unity site and forums  past few days trying to it to work. Could you please tell me  how do I point the script to the new image?

Comment: you only call RegisterRadarObject in Start in MakeRadObject script? this is where you place the image to the list of radar objects..

Comment: @joreldraw I think i understand, what you mean I have to use the Radar.RegisterRadarObjects in the scanRadar script?

Comment: yes , this is what i see on the script. You have a list of registered objects and in DrawRadarDots, the script got the list and draw each item whith their attached icon. You only need to call RegisterRadarObject and RemoveRadarObject

Comment: The reason this code doesn't work is because your RadarScan class doesn't modify the `RadarObject`s inside `Radar`, it just gets the default image for the GameObject and stores that value inside itself.